# How to use Zthread on windows?

Tags: windows

I have download the ZThread library([Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zthread/)). But am getting confused how to use the library and the header file. Can anyone provide me a guide how i can use it with Eclipse C++
under MinGW compiler?

Comment: Contact the author directly, I wouldn't be surprised that MinGW is not a supported platform: it should work under MSVC although may be broken on newer platforms judging by the date of the library (2005).

Comment: @Steve-o How can i use it with MSVC? can you provide me a guide for this?

Comment: [RTFM](http://zthread.sourceforge.net/documentation.html)?  It doesn't appear a wise choice to use a dead library, try [Boost thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread.html).